# NGINX PHP FastCGI Example の using unix socket change fastcgi_pass について

Tags: php, nginx

[PHP FastCGI Example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/)に下記のように掲載されていますが、

> If you’re using unix socket change fastcgi_pass to: fastcgi_pass
> unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;

Q1.「unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;」のパスについて
・これは固定パスですか？
・NGINXのバージョンによって変わるパスですか？
・PHPのバージョンによって変わるパスですか？
・任意に指定可能なパスですか？
・上記以外？

Q2.「unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;」ではない場合の対応について
現在、これではないパスを指定しているのですが(理由不明)、このパスに変更したほうがよいですか？
これは何か特別な意味があるパスですか？
変更することにより、例えば速度が少しでも速くなったりしますか？
※このパスを変更するには多数の設定ファイルを変更しなければいけないため、特別な意味があるパスなのか知りたく思い質問しました。

Comment: PHP FPMでUNIXソケットを使っていますか？

Comment: はい、使用しています。

Comment: PHP FPMのUNIXソケットのパスは何ですか？

Comment: 「/run/php-fpm/www.sock;」です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fastcgi_pass には、unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock を設定します。

nginxでPHPを呼び出す場合、通常はnginxのFastCGI接続モジュール [ngx_http_fastcgi_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html) を使います。FastCGIサーバーにはTCPまたはUNIXドメインソケット(UNIXソケットともいう)で接続します。接続するには、TCPなら「ホスト名またはIPアドレス:ポート番号」、UNIXドメインソケットなら「unix:ソケットのパス」を fastcgi_pass に指定します。PHPのFastCGIサーバーには通常PHP FPMを使うので、PHP FPMの設定でUNIXドメインソケットを指定してるなら、そこで設定しているソケットのパスをnginx側にも設定することになります。

Comment: 「PHP FPMの設定でUNIXドメインソケットを指定してるなら、そこで設定しているソケットのパスをnginx側にも設定」この意味は、一致さえしていれば任意のパスでOKという意味ですか？　例えば何かのバージョンによって「/var/run/php-fpm.sock;」が推奨されていたり「/run/php-fpm/www.sock;」が推奨されていたりしますか？

Comment: 私が答えらるのは同じにしないと動かないというだけです。「推奨」とかわかりません。

Comment: @re9 参考: [/run と /var/run の違いについて](https://linux-svr.com/tips/Linuxの豆知識/38.php)